# Odd behaviour for Windows Vista Ultimate login screen

Tags: windows-vista, passwords, login, username

Ever since I installed Vista Ultimate, after Windows loads the login screen has always started with the red circle with a white X and says "The user name or password are incorrect". I know this is not normal behaviour it should be showing me my list of users and then i can click on the user and be prompted for a password.

Has anyone experienced this and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have automatic logon configured with an incorrect username and/or password.

[KB315231](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) describes the various registry keys/values used by autologon. It says its for XP, but AFAIK it hasn't changed for Vista.

Comment: Seems likely to provoke such problem, but I don't see how it's possible to have such situation without touching registry. From what I know, you have to provide the login/password you want to autologin with, and it is checking if valid. So how such situation can occur in a regular use ?

Comment: The poster may have used some sort of software to change the key without realizing it, and when they changed their password it didn't update the registry key, leading to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a stuck key entering information as soon as the machine boots.